# How can i fix this error : Undefined property: stdClass::$order

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

```
$DetailedOrderList = $n11->DetailedOrderList([
    "productId"         => '',
    "status"            => 'new',
    "buyerName"         => '',
    "orderNumber"       => '',
    "productSellerCode" => '',
    "recipient"         => '',
    'sortForUpdateDate' => 'false',
    "period"            => [
        "startDate" => '?',
        "endDate"   => '?',
    ],
]);

$say = count($DetailedOrderList->orderList->order);
```

It's a my blade code.

> Undefined property: stdClass::$order error

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Can't really understand what you're showing as you've only shared the part that yields an error. Could you share the part where you create the stdClass?

Comment: I updated. How can i create stdClass ?

Comment: tr- eğer laravel kullanıyorsan std class kullanmak yerine doğrudan collection oluştur. Collectionun metodlarından da yararlarnırsın. (en - If you're using laravel as framework why don't you use collections for storing your data. thus you may use advanced collection methods) Burada hatayı alıyorsun çünkü obje içerisinde order diye bir property yok..

Comment: Try `dd($DetailedOrderList->orderList)` and you'll see either a) it's not an object or b) it doesn't have a order property in the object

Comment: tr- laravel kullanıyorum, bu kod ile nasıl kullanabilirim collection'u ?

Comment: dd($DetailedOrderList->orderList) = {#269}

Comment: detailedOrderListi ve orderlisti dd yapıp ss atar mısın ? Daha önce hiç n11 apisi kullanmadım, nasıl bir data getiriyor bilmiyorum. Birde itemleri kontrol eder misin order hiç mi yok yoksa sadece bazılarında mı yok

Comment: Not sure why it's not showing you the entire object all of it's properties, but there's no way that there is an order attribute on that object, check teoman's solution and you'll see it won't echo anything, add an else statement and you'll see it'll echo the else value

Comment: dd($DetailedOrderList->orderList); yapınca çıktı -> {#269}

dd($DetailedOrderList->orderList); yapınca çıktı ->

{#267 ▼
  +"result": {#268 ▼
    +"status": "success"
  }
  +"orderList": {#269}
  +"pagingData": {#270 ▼
    +"currentPage": 0
    +"pageSize": 100
    +"totalCount": 0
    +"pageCount": 0
  }
}

Comment: dd(DetailedOrderList->orderList) yaptığın zaman içinde hiç item gözükmüyor mu ?

Comment: çıktı olarak sadece **{#269}** veriyor.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error becuse php doesn't find any property named "order" in used stdclass

You may check whether this property exists or not. If exists you can display it

```
if(property_exists($stdClass,"order"))
{
  echo $stdClass->order;
}
```

Comment: Undefined variable: stdClass

Comment: @haktanyucel it was an example :) replace $stdClass with where order property should be in

Comment: Şöyle bir şey yap. say değeri count yaptığın sırada hata fırlatıyor. if property exists diye en yukarıda kontrol et eğer property varsa, ekrana yazdır o işlemleri. Eğer order yoksa sipariş de yok.  Yani yazdıracak bir şey de yok.. Orderlist içinde tam olarak nası bir data var bilmediğim için başka bir şey diyemiyorum. Ama beni anladığını uumuyorum.

Comment: if else yapınca else içine girdi if'i çalıştırmadı. teşekkürler yardımların için :)

Comment: Hocam if çalışmıyor çünkü order diye bir property yok orderlist içinde. orderlisti bir kez ekrana yazdırıp -dd ile- bana ss atar mısın ? ona göre bir şey söyleyebilirim.

Comment: status new olarak çektiğimde yeni sipariş bulamadığı için hata veriyormuş, delivered yaptığımda çekti.